# Can a class have a member of its own type?

Tags: oop

In order to emulate a containment relationship in which objects contain other instances of the same type, can I define a class as such?

```
class RussianDoll {

    string name;
    RussianDoll doll;

    RussianDoll();
}
```

How should I build the constructor(s) for this class?

Comment: The answer depends on the language used.

Comment: @Ignacio Which languages wouldn't allow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***Can a class have a member of its own type?***

Sure. It's actually quite common. Think of the case of a node in a linked list for instance:

```
class Node {
    Node next;
    int value;
}
```

> ***How should I build the constructor(s) for this class?***

You have several options (see below). You should obviously avoid creating new instances of the class in each invocation of the constructor as it would result in an infinite recursion.

- You could take a `Node` as argument and initialize it like

  ```
  this.next = nextArg;
  ```
- You could initialize it to the null-reference

  ```
  this.next = null;
  ```
- You could initialize it to `this`

  ```
  this.next = this;
  ```

(It's generally a bad idea to create a whole object graph inside a constructor any way so I wouldn't worry about this anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why not? As long as you are not instantiating it indefinitely.

```
class RussianDoll {
    RussianDoll parentDoll;

    RussianDoll(RussianDoll parentDoll) {
       this.parentDoll = parentDoll;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
A common example of this is a linked list.

However, you cannot unconditionally create the child in the constructor, or you'll create an infinite number of objects.